# Splunk dbxquery merge with splunk search

Tags: sql, splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to merge Splunk search query with a database query result set. Basically I have a Splunk dbxquery 1 which returns userid and email from database as follows for a particualr user id:

```
| dbxquery  connection="CMDB009" query="SELECT dra.value, z.email FROM DRES_PRINTABLE z, DRES.CREDENTIAL bc, DRES.CRATTR dra WHERE z.userid = bc.drid AND z.drid = dra.dredid AND dra.value in ('xy67383') "
```

Above query outputs

```
VALUE                                 EMAIL

xv67383                              xyz@test.com
```

Another query is a Splunk query 2 that provides the user ids as follows:

```
index=index1 (host=xyz OR host=ABC) earliest=-20m@m 
| rex field=_raw "samlToken\=(?>user>.+?):" 
| join type=outer usetime=true earlier=true username,host,user 
  [search index=index1 source="/logs/occurences.log" SERVER_SERVER_CONNECT NOT AMP  earliest=@w0  
  | rex field=_raw "Origusername\((?>username>.+?)\)" 
  |  rex field=username"^(?<user>,+?)\:" 
  | rename _time as epoch1] 
|  "stats count by user | sort -count | table user
```

This above query 2 returns a column called user but not email.

What I want to do is add a column called email from splunk dbxquery 1 for all matching rows by userid in output of query 1. Basically want to add email as additional field for each user returned in query 2.

What I tried so far is this but it does not give me any results. Any help would be appreciated.

```
index=index1 (host=xyz OR host=ABC) earliest=-20m@m 
| rex field=_raw "samlToken\=(?>user>.+?):" 
| join type=outer usetime=true earlier=true username,host,user 
  [search index=index1 source="/logs/occurences.log" SERVER_SERVER_CONNECT NOT AMP  earliest=@w0  
  | rex field=_raw "Origusername\((?>username>.+?)\)" 
  |  rex field=username"^(?<user>,+?)\:" 
  | rename _time as epoch1] 
|  "stats count by user | sort -count 
| table user 
| map search="| | dbxquery  connection=\"CMDB009\" query=\"SELECT dra.value, z.email FROM DRES_PRINTABLE z, DRES.CREDENTIAL bc, DRES.CRATTR dra WHERE z.userid = bc.drid AND z.drid = dra.dredid AND dra.value in ('$user'):\""
```

Comment: Try `$user$` instead of `$user` in the `map` command.

Comment: Thanks, that works and shows the table as user and email (2 columns) which is good. But when I add username field to the table directive as follows, I expect to see username column as well along with user and email but it does not show username columne with below.                                                                       
  ......table |username , user | map search="| | dbxquery  connection=\"CMDB009\" query=\"SELECT dra.value, z.email FROM DRES_PRINTABLE z, DRES.CREDENTIAL bc, DRES.CRATTR dra WHERE z.userid = bc.drid AND z.drid = dra.dredid AND dra.value in ('$user'):\""

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$user` with `$user$` in the `map` command.  Splunk uses a `$` on each end of a token.

The `username` field is not available at the end of the query because the `stats` command stripped it out.  The only fields available after `stats` are the ones mentioned in the command (user and count in this case).  To make the username field available, add it to the `stats` command.  That may, however, change your results.

````
| rex field=_raw "samlToken\=(?<user>.+?):" 
| join type=outer usetime=true earlier=true username,host,user 
  [search index=index1 source="/logs/occurences.log" SERVER_SERVER_CONNECT NOT AMP  earliest=@w0  
  | rex field=_raw "Origusername\((?<username>.+?)\)" 
  |  rex field=username"^(?<user>,+?)\:" 
  | rename _time as epoch1] 
| stats count by user, username | sort -count 
| table user, username 
| map search="| dbxquery  connection=\"CMDB009\" query=\"SELECT dra.value, z.email FROM DRES_PRINTABLE z, DRES.CREDENTIAL bc, DRES.CRATTR dra WHERE z.userid = bc.drid AND z.drid = dra.dredid AND dra.value in ('$user'):\""```
````

Comment: Thaks I tried that but it only shows value and email column. Still do not see the user column.  I think it may be because the sql query is only listing out value and email?

Comment: Makes sense.  If the DBX query isn't using username then it may not show up in the results.

Comment: Problem is the username is not available in the db so cannot be returned as part of dbx query. It is being returned via index 1. I am thinking of storing the output of dbx  in inputlookup and then using that to join with the index search. Is there a  better way to do this?

Comment: There may be a better way, but I can't think of it ATM.  Use lookup files as a scratchpad is an old, but workable approach.